# wget saved my link as if it was a file instead of adding text to the file I specified. How do I delete the link?

Tags: bash, shell

Running openSUSE tumbleweed (lowest package) and I used `wget` to try to save only the text from a webpage. However, when I list files and directories from my homepage the text file and the link appear separately like so

```
bin     firstScript     file.txt     MyFirst    randomLink.lnk?idclass=id REMEMBER.sh
```

When I try to remove the link I cant seem to find it.

`rm randomLink.lnk?idclass=id` doesn't work and it neither does `find randomLink.lnk?idclass=id`.

What have I done? How do I rid myself of this weird link?

Answer (score 1):

If the file was named `randomLink.lnk?idclass=id`, `rm randomLink.lnk?idclass=id` would have worked, so I think it's actually named `randomLink.lnk?idclass=id REMEMBER.sh`, which fits with how `ls` is showing it. So simply quote it:

```
rm "randomLink.lnk?idclass=id REMEMBER.sh"
```

If that doesn't work, get the filename in shell-quoted form, so that you can copy-paste it:

```
printf '%q\n' *
```

This will print each filename on its own line, and you'll need to copy-paste the whole line containing the problem filename for `rm` to work.

*Due credit to [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) for suggesting this in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61808141/how-do-i-delete-a-file-that-shows-with-ls-command-but-cannot-be-found-otherwis#comment109325446_61808141) on Stack Overflow*